# Override default initializer of superclass in different swift files

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, swift

I wrote class Vehicle in Vehicle.swift and inherited it in another class Bicycle in Bicycle.swift. But Xcode 6.1 reported an compile error: initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass.
Vehicle.swift:

```
import Foundation

public class Vehicle {
    var numberOfWheels: Int?
    var description: String {
        return "\(numberOfWheels) wheel(s)"
    }
}
```

Bicycle.swift:

```
import Foundation

public class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        numberOfWheels = 2
    }
}
```

Those codes are from Apple iOS Developer Library. Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_324

When in the same .swift file, they can pass the compile. Only do not work in different files. Is this a bug of swift?

Comment: It should work ok if you give numberOfWheels a default value in the Vehicle class. My understanding of the docs would suggest that using Int? should also work (since it gets a default value of nil), but that appears not to be the case.

Comment: Yes, that works. Maybe explicit init() declaration is the appropriate way by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, Default Initializer is invisible from other files, as if it's declared as `private init() {}`. 
<s>I've not found any official documents about this behavior, though.</s> I think it's a bug.

Anyway, explicit `init()` declaration solves the problem.

```
public class Vehicle {

    init() {} // <- HERE

    var numberOfWheels: Int?
    var description: String {
        return "\(numberOfWheels) wheel(s)"
    }
}
```

OR as @rdelmar says in comment, explicit initial value of `numberOfWheels` also works:

```
public class Vehicle {
    var numberOfWheels: Int? = nil
    var description: String {
        return "\(numberOfWheels) wheel(s)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this: For a type that is defined as public, the default initializer is considered internal. Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-XID_29

Comment: So, this must be a bug, I think.

Comment: Possible related Developer Forum topic: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1036670#1036670

Comment: This might be the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bicycle is not a **public** class. Code from Apple's Library:

```
class Bicycle: Vehicle {
    override init() {
       super.init()
       numberOfWheels = 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the error still remains after public removed.

Comment: And Internal should be accessed by other classes in the project.